# Is there a way to get twitter Screen name or user Id with users email address or firstname and last name?

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to get twitter Screen name or user Id with users email address or firstname and last name?

I have a small list of user details consist of first name , last name email address.
So is it possible to get the screen name or user id via twitter api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to search for usernames using a string (e.g. first name and/or last name).  The API documentation on this [is here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search).  As for a search based on an email address, that would depend on the privacy settings for each user and whether or not the email address you have is the same one they used for their account.  Chances are you will have less luck with that than with the name.